# Can moderators be affected by the manipulated/independent variable?

Tags: regression, interaction

I was wondering whether I can use a measured variable as a moderator in a linear regression. Say I have a manipulated variable X, and two measured variables Y and Z. There is a main effect of X on Y, but not of either X or Y on Z. But I want to know if X*Y predicts Z. Can I do this? Is the “multicollinearity" between X and Y a problem?

For example, 
X = exercise v. control
Y = heartrate at rest
Z = risk of diabetes

Say exercise (relative to control) affects heartrate, but not risk of diabetes (i.e., there's no main effect of X on Z). Furthermore, heartrate does not affect risk of diabetes (i.e., no main effect of Y on Z). But I want to know if exercise is more effective at reducing risk of diabetes among people whose heartrates are lower (regardless of whether heartrate is lower because of exercise or not). Can I just run a linear regression with an interaction term? Or do I have a multicollinearity problem?

I don't know if I've expressed this clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collinearity is a problem when two predictor variables are almost perfectly correlated, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Your proposal to run regression with an interaction term seems like a reasonable way to proceed. If your outcome is "risk of diabetes," on a probability scale from 0 to 1, you should be using a logistic regression rather than a standard linear regression.

Do not, however, be so quick to assume things like "heartrate does not affect risk of diabetes." There is always a problem in cases like this in distinguishing correlation from causation. There might be no obvious reason to you why heart rate per se might affect risk of diabetes, but there might well be an underlying hidden variable (like propensity to develop metabolic syndrome in this case) that affects both in parallel.